# Python - Fast approach to merging two list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have two list of lists (containing integers), the first list is the "seed" list, the second is considered the "new" list.  I want to grow the seed list with lists that are in the new list but not in the seed list, plus lists that are similar (not disjoint) to one another between the seed and new list by `list(set(seedList[index1] + newList[index2]))`.  The end result will be the seed list having grown from unique lists within the new list, and expanding similar lists between the seed and new lists.  Wow, not sure if that makes sense.

Seed List
`[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]`

New List
`[[1,2], [6,7], [9]]`

Final List
`[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [9]]`

** Edit **

I realized after posting this problem that I perhaps forced my self into a corner by seeking a solution that required a list of lists.  The greater context is there are two files: seed and new.  Each file has a logical grouping of IDs per row.  I need to merge the two files but keep the logical grouping of each row.  So if two rows are the same between the seed and new file (i.e. 1,2,3 == 1,2,3), leave the row in the seed file alone, if two rows are "similar" (not disjoint, i.e. 6,7,8 ~ 6,7)) then merge the two rows (no duplicates) and update the row in the seed file, if there is a unique row in the new file (not in the seed file, i.e. 9) add it to the seed file.

Seed File

```
1,2,3
4,5
6,7,8
```

New File

```
1,2
6,7
9
```

Final File

```
1,2,3
4,5
6,7,8
9
```

Comment: So... you want a list that contains separate lists. And if any list in the new list is a subset of a list in the old list, you want to not add it to the final list? Otherwise add the list to the final list? And I'm curious, what are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: What happens if you 'merge' `seed_list = [[1,2], [3,4]]` and `new_list = [[2, 3]]`? `final_list = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]`?

Comment: @MichaelHoff The way in which you show the seed_list is possible.  However, the example of the new_list you showed would never occur simply due to logic in how the two lists are created to begin with.

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro I've realized by posing the problem in form a lists of lists that I may have limited the possible algorithms for solving.  I am going to add additional context to the original problem that will hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For huge amounts of data the following approach using an index map might be faster. If you want to `merge` multiple times, you might want to keep the index structure up-to-date (not sure if that makes a big difference, though).

```
seeds = list(map(set, [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]))
groups = list(map(set, [[1,2], [6,7], [9]]))

def merge(seeds, groups, idx=None):
    if idx is None:
        idx = dict((k, s) for s in seeds for k in s)
    mapped_values = set(idx.keys())
    for new_group in groups:
        common_values = new_group.intersection(mapped_values)
        if common_values:
            mapped_group = idx[common_values.pop()]
            # assert all(mapped_group == idx[v] for v in common_values)
            mapped_group.update(new_group)
        else:
            mapped_group = new_group
            seeds.append(new_group)
        #############################################
        # keep index up-to-date, required only if...
        # - we would want to reuse the index
        # - new groups are not pairwise disjoint
        #
        # for v in new_group:
        #     idx[v] = mapped_group
        # mapped_values.update(new_group)
        #############################################

print(seeds)
print(groups)
merge(seeds, groups)
print(seeds)

# [set([1, 2, 3]), set([4, 5]), set([8, 6, 7])]
# [set([1, 2]), set([6, 7]), set([9])]
# [set([1, 2, 3]), set([4, 5]), set([8, 6, 7]), set([9])]
```

Condensed version, assuming all preconditions and 'optimized' for one merge only:

```
def merge(seeds, groups):
    idx = dict((k, s) for s in seeds for k in s)
    mapped_values = set(idx.keys())
    for new_group in groups:
        common_values = new_group.intersection(mapped_values)
        if common_values:
            idx[common_values.pop()].update(new_group)
        else:
            seeds.append(new_group)
```

Comment: The condensed version is extremely fast and worked as described.  The seed file started out at 20M rows and each subsequent file grew until about 60M.  Great performance.

Comment: Nice! I would be interested in a comparison to the other approaches. Could you do that with your dataset?

Answer (score 1):

It 's a bit messy but it works

```
Seed_List = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]
New_List = [[1,2], [6,7], [9]]

Seed_List += [ 
    nl for nl in New_List 
    if sum([ 1 for sl in Seed_List if all(l in sl for l in nl) ]) == 0 
]
```

Output :

```
print(Seed_List)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

I hope it 's helpful

Comment: `[1, 2]` has to be part of the final list, because it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @QuoVadis  yes but neither is `[6,7]` , I don't think that's what the OP asked for

Comment: there is no duplicate for `[6, 7]`. It is not to be confused with `[6, 7, 8]`. Those are two different lists.

Comment: @QuoVadis yes but `[6, 7]` is a subset of `[6, 7, 8]` , as `[1, 2]` is a subset of `[1, 2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
seed = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]

new = [[1,2], [6,7], [9]]

flat_seed = [i for j in seed for i in j]
flat_new = [i for j in new for i in j]

seed.append([])

for i in flat_new:
    if i not in flat_seed:
        seed[-1].append(i)
        flat_seed.append(i)

print seed
```